# Hide/ Show Static Section Header in Swift Programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to hide/show static table rows and section header when a switch is toggled in Swift. I'm able to hide the rows but when trying to hide one section header view, the other starts disappearing when I turn the toggle back on.

This is what my code looks like:

```
@IBAction func toggleSound(sender: UISwitch) {

    if(sender.on) {
        self.sectionInVisible = false


    }
    else{
        self.sectionInVisible = true
    }


    let section = 1

    let secPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(secPath)?.hidden = sectionInVisible
    self.tableView.headerViewForSection(section)?.hidden = sectionInVisible

    let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section)
    for row in 0..<numberOfRows {
        let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path)?.accessoryType = .None
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path)?.hidden = sectionInVisible

    }


    self.tableView.reloadData()


}
```

What am I missing? I tried changing height as well but I think its not going to work for a static table.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is wrong:

```
self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(secPath)?.hidden = sectionInVisible
```

The way to remove rows is to call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. And similarly for sections, there is a `deleteSections` command.

(You will also need to change the underlying data so that the section does not have those, or, if you're hiding the whole section, so that the section appears not to exist at all. You will, as you have already guessed, have trouble doing that with a static table.)